# Node js FileHandle read method throws invalid argument error

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

According to Node docs, FileHandle.read() takes two types of arguments, multiple objects, or one object. However, when I pass object, I get: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "buffer" argument must be an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object.`

Docs reference is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_read_buffer_offset_length_position) for regular read and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_read_options) for "object" read.

"Object" read says that it was added in: v13.11.0.
I'm using v14.4.0.

Here is code I'm using:

```
    fs_p.open(FILENAME, 'r')
        .then((fileHandler) => {
            console.log(fileHandler);
            const dyn_head = Buffer.alloc(12);

            fileHandler.read({ buffer: dyn_head })
                .then((bytesRead, buffer) => {
                    console.log("Reading")
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("err")
        });
```

`fs_p` is fs.promises.

In case that you are wondering why I'm using "object" read, I sometimes won't use all parameters, and I want to make code clean.

If it helps. I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, that form of `.read()` just does not work in node v14.  I traced into it in the debugger and it goes right to this code:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/promises.js#L251

```
async function read(handle, buffer, offset, length, position) {
  validateFileHandle(handle);
  validateBuffer(buffer);            // <== fails here

  if (offset == null) {
    offset = 0;
  } else {
    validateInteger(offset, 'offset');
  }

  length |= 0;

  if (length === 0)
    return { bytesRead: length, buffer };

  if (buffer.length === 0) {
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE('buffer', buffer,
                                    'is empty and cannot be written');
  }

  validateOffsetLengthRead(offset, length, buffer.length);

  if (!NumberIsSafeInteger(position))
    position = -1;

  const bytesRead = (await binding.read(handle.fd, buffer, offset, length,
                                        position, kUsePromises)) || 0;

  return { bytesRead, buffer };
}
```

And, the call to `validateBuffer()` throws immediately if you try to use the `handle.read(options)` form.  So, this appears to just be a bug (in either the doc or the implementation, I'm not sure which).  In any case, you will just have to switch to the other form of `.read()` where you pass each argument separately.

Your code will work if you change from this:

```
fileHandler.read({ buffer: dyn_head }).then((bytesRead, buffer) => {
```

to this:

```
fileHandler.read(dyn_head, 0, dyn_head.length, 0).then(({bytesRead, buffer}) => {
```

Note, that you also have to change your `.then()` as your arguments were wrong there too.  That wasn't the cause of the problem you write about because you weren't getting there yet, but you also have to fix that.

---

P.S. I tried searching for an open bug report on this issue, but did not find one, though I'm not sure I really know how to search nodejs bugs very well.  Perhaps you should file a bug report.

Comment: Yes! Omg, thank you for getting your hands dirty. I also have searched for reported bug, couldn't find it. I'll check on how to report it, and let the team know.

Comment: @branisha - If you file a bug, let me know here so I can follow its progress.  I filed one earlier on a stream problem and it was interesting to follow the process of someone fixing it, verifying it with testing and then merging the fix in.  While I'm capable of creating bug fixes, I don't understand Github or the process well enough to actually do all that other stuff (besides writing and testing the code fix).

Comment: I just created one [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34176). Actually, I never did a bugfix on open project. This one shouldn't be complicated, so I will try to fix it myself, and try to get familiar with the process. Cheers.